# Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later

Tags: facebook, authentication

Starting yesterday at 4pm all of my Facebook Connect Apps stopped accepting new users. This is across numerous Apps on various domains.

I get the FB dialog which pops up and requests initial permissions.

After I press ok, I get the following error:

*Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.*

```
I actually tried to join StackOverflow yesterday and got the exact same error, but StackOverflow seems to be working today. 

Unfortunately all of my sites are still down.

Any suggestions are welcome!
```